# html navigation bar does not display inline

Tags: html, css

I would like to implement the navigation bar style used by this open source software (http://demo.openrem.org/openrem/ct/) which uses django as a web framework. I have have grabbed the html and css from the source that I think I require. However my nav-bar does not display inline, has bullet points in the list (https://jsfiddle.net/1prLa21x/1/). I think I am missing some additional css style settings. Any pointers on how to get closer to the navbar displayed by the openrem page?

HTML

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
     <div class="container">        
         <div class="navbar-header">
             <a class="navbar-brand" href="/openrem/">nc_jobs</a>
         </div>
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">    
                <li><a href="#">Done</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Not Done</a></li>
              </ul>     
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
             <p class="navbar-text navbar-right">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                 Welcome test.user - 
                  <a href="/logout/" class="navbar-link">logout</a>
             </p>
         </ul>
         </div>
     </div>        
</div>
```

CSS

```
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #7092be;
  border-color: #145ebe;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: #e0eaf6;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-text {
  color: #e0eaf6;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #e0eaf6;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #145ebe;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #145ebe;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #145ebe;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background-color: #145ebe;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background-color: #e0eaf6;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-default .navbar-form {
  border-color: #e0eaf6;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link {
  color: #e0eaf6;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #e0eaf6;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #145ebe;
  }
}
```

Comment: check if the path of your stylesheet is right. Edit : Sorry I just read the CSS, you indeed miss some css. Nothing here remove the list style nor display inline-block or float.

Comment: The code you have is missing list-style definitions. Are you sure you downloaded all the 4 external CSS files? I suggest you to get the 6 Javascript files, too. With Firefox look in the information window about the page: they are listed under "dependencies".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That example is running off the bootstrap framework -

if you add https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css as an external resource to your fiddle it displays correctly.

You can download the whole source at getbootstrap.com

Comment: Excellent. I hadnt got to bootstrap on the w3 schools website

Comment: awesome- it's a great tool - have fun with it!